# Why would you want to cast [NSNull null]

Tags: ios, casting

I don't understand what this if statement is doing. Why cast [NSNull null] this way ?

```
CAAnimation *action = (CAAnimation *)[self actionForLayer:layer forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
    if (action != (CAAnimation *)[NSNull null])
    {
        //Stuff
    }
```

Found it on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nicklockwood/d374033b27c62662ac8d) 
Feel like a noob!

Comment: Probably to suppress a type comparison warning.

Comment: I wouldn't describe that as cast to `[NSNull null]`; rather it's a test for `[NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement may return a NSNull value (please note that NSNull is not nil) instead of CAAnimation instance in case if no such animation exists for key "backgroundColor".

```
CAAnimation *action = (CAAnimation *)[self actionForLayer:layer forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
```

To know about NSNull please see [Apple Documentation on NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/).

So if you compare like the following the condition will fail, since in this case the return value NSNull.

```
if (action != nil)
{
    //Stuff
}
```

so your code should make sure that it not processing a NSNull value. You can also use the following code to do the same.

```
if (action != nil && [action isKindOfClass:[CAAnimation class]])
{
    //Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the blog you read, you can read it like this

> In the code below, we create a UILabel subclass called FancyLabel, and override actionForLayer:forKey: so that it returns [CATransition animation] for the contents key instead of [NSNull null] (which is what the method returns normally):

So,this method can return `[NSNull null]`.

Then the test code is

```
    CAAnimation *action = (CAAnimation *)[NSNull null];
if (action == (CAAnimation *)[NSNull null])
{
    NSLog(@"Same Address");
}
```

This will log `Same Address`

So if I try to delete the cast

```
   CAAnimation *action = (CAAnimation *)[NSNull null];
if (action == [NSNull null])
{
    NSLog(@"Same Address");
}
```

It will still log `Same address`,but gives a **warning**

So,since [NSNull null] is singleton, if two pointer point to it ,it must be `==`.

**Therefore,Here is just suppress warning**

Answer (score -1):

Objective-C style says nil is what to use for the id type (and pointers to objects).
C style says that NULL is what you use for void *.
C++ style typically says that you should just use 0.